# Raspberry pi in Proteus

Tags: raspberry-pi

I would like to ask which version of raspberry pi is supported in Proteus. 
I am not sure raspberry pi 1 raspberry pi 2 or raspberry pi 3 is supported. 
Do you have any idea which is supported? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yeah I didn't find anything for "Protheus" either XD

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to software development. Maybe try https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Why not related.. You can develop code for rasp pi

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry pi 3. This is the right answer.